# python3 --version command not returning correct version

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, terminal, homebrew

I am trying to upgrade to the most recent version of python, which is currently 3.8.5.

When I type `python3 --version`, I get:

`Python 3.7.0`

So it appears my python is not up-to-date.  I then type `brew upgrade python` and get a warning:

`Warning: python 3.8.5 already installed`

So, again, I type `python3 --version`, and again I get:

`Python 3.7.0`

Why is `python3 --version` not returning Python 3.8.5?

(PS - if I type `python --version` I get Python 2.7.11 as expected for my Mac)

Comment: You probably need to `brew link python`, or run `brew doctor` to see if everything is OK.

Answer (score 1):

Homebrew is installing python 3.8.5 to a different path. Try:

```
brew link python3
brew update
brew upgrade python3
brew cleanup python3
```

Comment: Thanks, I did that but afterward I still get version 3.7.0.   Any ideas?

Comment: In the terminal type which python3.8 and then which python3.7 and then let me know the paths that is returned

Comment: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3

Comment: Any thoughts on this?  When I type `which python3.8` I get: `/usr/local/bin/python3.8`

Comment: And when I type `which python3.7` I get `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7
`

Comment: Ah.  I think I figured this out.  I needed to put /usr/local/bin earlier in the $PATH, so I typed: `export PATH="/my/directory/bin:$PATH"` and now, when I type python --version, I  get 3.8.5.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You may have multiple python binaries on your system but the system path is finding 3.7.0. The command **which python3** will show the path of your current python binary.

It might be worthwhile taking a look at the system path with **echo $PATH** to see where your system is looking for Python

Updating your system environment using export as below should enable the system to find python3.8.5

`PATH="/path/to/python3.8.5/bin:${PATH}"`

`export PATH`

Comment: Thanks.  I see that somehow python3.8 is being stored in the wrong place, but this did not fix the issue.  Any ideas?   When I type `which python3` I get `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7
` but when I type `which python3.8` I get `/usr/local/bin/python3.8`

Comment: Ah.  I think I figured this out.  I needed to put /usr/local/bin earlier in the $PATH, so I typed: `export PATH="/my/directory/bin:$PATH"` and now, when I type python --version, I  get 3.8.5.  Thanks!